# How to express the "*" denoting any text containing part of text when using IF function?

Tags: google-sheets

When using this formula:
`=if(AND('CASES LIST'!R4="No",P5="*neuro*"),"check","")`

I am looking for the cell P5 if the text contains "neuro" in the text but it doesn't work when I add star* before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards are not supported in simple `IF` formulas

Use the following

```
=if(AND($R$4="No";REGEXMATCH(P5;"neuro"));"check";"")
```

You can even turn it to an array using:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(($R$4="No")*(REGEXMATCH(P5:P,"neuro")),"check",""))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)

Comment: Remember you can always upvote an answer as well :)